# @"{\"details\": \"A friend request is already pending.\"}" how to retrieve the value from this json string

Tags: ios, json

@"{\"details\": \"A friend request is already pending.\"}".. This is a json string coming from the server. i want to retrieve the object in a one string i.e is A friend request is already pending string is to be in one string. please tell me how to retrieve this.

i tried like this

```
NSString *str = @"{\"details\": \"A friend request is already pending.\"}";

NSLog(@"%@",str);

NSString *resultStr1 = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
NSString *resultStr2 = [resultStr1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];


//NSLog(@"%@",resultStr2);


//NSString *encodestr = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

// NSLog(@"%@",encodestr);

```
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

data = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length] - 1)];

NSLog(@"%@",data);

NSError *error =Nil;

NSArray *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",JSON);

NSLog(@"%@",[JSON valueForKey:@"details"]);
```

Comment: What is the output of those NSLog() methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. COnvert your string into a dictionary and access it by keys. This will be helpful when you come across large group of data.

```
NSString *str = @"{\"details\": \"A friend request is already pending.\"}";

    NSData *data    =   [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError* error;

    NSDictionary* dic   =   [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dic objectForKey:@"details"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it will help you

```
NSDictionary *JSON = 
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                      error: &e];


NSLog(@"%@",[JSON valueForKey:@"details"]);
```

Comment: NSString *str1 = @"{\"details\": \"A friend request is already pending.\"}";
    
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
    
    NSData *data1    = [str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSError* error1;
    
    NSDictionary* dic1   = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error1];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [dic1 objectForKey:@"details"]);
thank you guys .. this code is working properly....

Comment: You should probably be using `objectForKey:` with `NSDictionary` rather than `valueForKey:`. The latter is defined by KVO, while the former is the actual getter for dictionaries.